# how can i make sure that the code will not run after a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

I have a piece of code in which i run 2 promises.

The problem is that the second promise runs while the first promise is still running. this is causing me so many problems.
I want that the second promise will not run, until i get an answer from the first promise.

I don't want to put the second promise inside the first one.

Somebody knows how can i achieve this? Is it possible to use Async await?

Here is my code:

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    if (!checkIfOrderValid(req.body)) {
        return res.sendStatus(400);
    }
    let order = new Order(req.body);
    order._UserId = '5b58836ed741e92d7416002e';

    //first check if the seats are taken
    /*
    this is working. but gives me 
    "(node:14552) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): Error: Can't set
    headers after they are sent."
    when the seats are taken. check it out
    */
    Show.findById(req.body._ShowId).then(show => {
        req.body.ticketsPositions.forEach(element => {
            console.log('checking: ' + element[0] + "-" + element[1]);
            if (show.showTakenSeats.hasOwnProperty(element[0] + "-" + element[1])){
                console.log('seat are already taken!');
                return res.status(400).json({'message': 'Seats are already taken!'})
            }
        });
    });

    order.save().then(newOrder => {
        console.log("Order saved successfully");
        res.json(newOrder);
    }, err => {
        res.send(err);
    });
});
```

Many thanks!

Comment: On a separate note: It's a problem to have return res.status(...).json(...)` inside a `.forEach()`.  It isn't stopping your `.forEach()` loop and you may be trying to send multiple responses so that part of the design is a bit messed up.

Comment: You can accomplish your goal either by chaining promises (no nesting required) or by using async/await.  There are thousands of articles written on both if you want to do a little research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't want to put the second promise inside the first one.

Well...that's what you do, effectively:

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    if (!checkIfOrderValid(req.body)) {
        return res.sendStatus(400);
    }
    let order = new Order(req.body);
    order._UserId = '5b58836ed741e92d7416002e';

    Show.findById(req.body._ShowId)
        .then(show => {
            // Make sure all seats are okay; notice we don't do `res.send` here,
            // we just see if every seat is available
            const seatsOkay = req.body.ticketPositions.every(element => {
                console.log('checking: ' + element[0] + "-" + element[1]);
                return !show.showTakenSeats.hasOwnProperty(element[0] + "-" + element[1]);
            });
            if (seatsOkay) {
                // Yes, order
                return order.save().then(newOrder => {
                    console.log("Order saved successfully");
                    res.json(newOrder);
                });
            } else {
                // Nope, send response -- ONCE, not in the ticketPositions loop
                console.log('seat are already taken!');
                res.status(400).json({'message': 'Seats are already taken!'})
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.send(err);
        });
});
```

On any vaguely-modern version of Node, you can use an `async` function instead. Just be sure to catch errors, since `router.post` won't handle errors for you (you might look at [koa](http://koajs.com)):

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        if (!checkIfOrderValid(req.body)) {
            return res.sendStatus(400);
        }
        let order = new Order(req.body);
        order._UserId = '5b58836ed741e92d7416002e';

        // Get this show
        const show = await Show.findById(req.body._ShowId);

        // Make sure all seats are okay
        const seatsOkay = req.body.ticketPositions.every(element => {
            console.log('checking: ' + element[0] + "-" + element[1]);
            return !show.showTakenSeats.hasOwnProperty(element[0] + "-" + element[1]);
        });
        if (seatsOkay) {
            // Yes, order
            const newOrder = await order.save();
            console.log("Order saved successfully");
            res.json(newOrder);
        } else {
            // Nope, send error response
            console.log('seat are already taken!');
            res.status(400).json({'message': 'Seats are already taken!'})
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version using async/await.  Amazing how it flattens things out and makes the error handling simplified.  The catch will catch all exceptions in both awaits (thrown or rejected), and thrown in the method itself.

Also, you don't want to throw inside a forEach.  Use filter instead to find the condition you are looking for.  If you need async stuff in the loop, that's another issue altogether.

```js
router.post("/", async(req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!checkIfOrderValid(req.body)) {
      return res.sendStatus(400);
    }
    let order = new Order(req.body);
    order._UserId = '5b58836ed741e92d7416002e';

    var show = await Show.findById(req.body._ShowId)

    var taken = req.body.ticketsPositions.find(element => {
      return show.showTakenSeats.hasOwnProperty(element[0] + "-" + element[1])
    });
    if (taken) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        'message': 'Seats Taken'
      })
    }

    var newOrder = await order.save().json()

    res.send.json(newOrder);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err)
  }
});
```